# Динамическое добавление элемента li к элементу ul

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Изучаю `jQuery`. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `the button` в список `ul` добавлялся `li`. Пробую делать так и не понимаю почему не работает:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#superButton").on("click", addLiToUl);
            function addLiToUl() {
                $("p > ul").append("<li>Hello!</li>");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <ul> Some things:</ul>
    </p>
    <input id="superButton" type="button" value="the button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` является блочным элементом, и не может находиться **внутри** элемента `p`. Поэтому браузер меняет разметку на следующую

```
<p></p>
<ul> Some things:</ul>
<p></p>
```

И в таком виде селектор `p>ul` возвращает пустую коллекцию.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#superButton").on("click", addLiToUl);

  function addLiToUl() {
    $("ul").append("<li>Hello!</li>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>Some things:</ul>

<input id="superButton" type="button" value="the button" />
```